# How to retrieve the start time of a live event on YouTube?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm trying to go back and sync completed or in-progress live event with real-world timestamps (for example, a twitter play-by-play.)  I don't own the live events in question.  Obviously this is only useful for events that can be rewound or replayed (such as many of the gaming-related broadcasts)

Is there a way to retrieve the start time of a live event?

I've tried the following:

Using player.getDuration():

> If the currently playing video is a live event, the getDuration() function will return the elapsed time since the live video stream began. Specifically, this is the amount of time that the video has streamed without being reset or interrupted. In addition, this duration is commonly longer than the actual event time since streaming may begin before the event's start time.

This doesn't seem to be always accurate - if a live event has a set broadcast duration, this seems to instead return the total time that the broadcast is scheduled for.  here is a random video that exhibits that behaviour: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-Bb5F8Jcwg (found via http://www.youtube.com/live/all)

I've also tried using the data api and grabbing the publish time from the snippet, but this usually appears to be a few hours or days before the broadcast actually begins.

As a non-content owner, is there any way to retrieve this time?

Thanks!

EDIT:
After looking further, I found developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/… which appears to offer this information under the yt:when for each event... so I guess my revised question would be - is there a way to retrieve this given a video ID, or do I always need to find it through the live events api?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) for this.

You can do a [videos->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) with id=VIDEO_ID

You can get duration from [contentDetails.duration](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.duration) from the response.

---

If the content was your own, you could use v3 [Live Streaming API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/) for this.

You can do a [liveBroadcasts->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list) with id=VIDEO_ID

You can calculate duration with [snippet.actualStartTime](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#snippet.actualStartTime) and [snippet.actualEndTime](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#snippet.actualStartTime) from the response.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but does this only work for broadcasts that I own?  In the API explorer, entering the example id I used in my original post returns me a 403 with this error:   `"errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.liveBroadcasts",
    "reason": "insufficientLivePermissions",
    "message": "Request is not authorized",
    "extendedHelp": "https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list#auth_required"
   }`

Comment: To use Live API you need to have a channel that's enabled for live streaming, and you can use it against that channel.

Answer (score 2):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35889354/return-upcoming-youtube-api-v3-video-schedule-date).

The summary version is:

- Use the Data API v3
- To find scheduled live events on a channel, use the **search** endpoint with a channelId, type=video and eventType=upcoming
- To retrieve the start time of an upcoming event, use the **videos** endpoint with part=liveStreamingDetails

Answer (score 1):

You can query for the `liveStreamingDetails` part of a given video ID with the [Videos:list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) Youtube API.

Then you'll have something like this in the reposne:

```json
"liveStreamingDetails": {
        "actualStartTime": "2023-06-10T20:33:25Z",
        "actualEndTime": "2023-06-10T22:44:31Z"
      }
```

Comment: Comments on other responses suggest they can only be used on your own broadcasts. I was able to use this on a broadcast and channel that I do not own.