# Getting realtime information about live streaming on YouTube

Tags: youtube-api

I am building a webpage to display the live streaming status of several YouTube channels which I do not manage. The page will display a list of selected channels, with a ● **red dot** beside any channel which is live streaming right now. I also want the webpage to update that status in realtime, so if a channel begins live streaming, I need to immediately add the dot, and when a channel stops live streaming, I need to immediately remove the dot.

I can use the Data API to:

- find upcoming events on a channel, using the `search` endpoint with a `channelId`, `type=video` and `eventType=upcoming`
- retrieve the `scheduledStartTime` of an upcoming event, using the `videos` endpoint with `part=liveStreamingDetails`
- find live events on a channel, using the `search` endpoint with a `channelId`, `type=video` and `eventType=live`
- retrieve the `actualStartTime` of a live event, using the `videos` endpoint with `part=liveStreamingDetails`
- retrieve the `actualEndTime` of a completed event, using the `videos` endpoint with `part=liveStreamingDetails`

I would really like to avoid polling the `videos` endpoint to monitor the status of live streams. Can I subscribe to a set of channel IDs or video IDs, to receive a message in real time when:

- when an upcoming event actually starts live streaming
- when a live stream is completed/terminated
- for channels which I don't manage?

Is this possible?

Comment: I would also like this. All I can find is https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications from 2015, but only gives updates for a few events, and so old that I bet it doesn't work anymore. I found that Twitch has a better solution, using WebSub, https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/webhooks-guide. Not that it helps you but perhaps could be of interest.