# YouTube API: get live stream start time and current length

Tags: youtube-api

I'm trying to get data about a live stream I started.
So far I had no luck in getting any usefull data. I tried the API explorer but all I can get is a list of my live streams: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams/list

I want to know the **exact time the live stream started** and what the **current length** is.

This way I can calculate certain moments in time and provide a link for the user to jump to (using the `&t` query parameter)

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29132359/4092887) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18069168/4092887) might help you. The second link is something I was thinking for suggest you: get the `VIDEO_ID` and get the contentDetails properties.